# how to make this work with jquery 1.12.4

Tags: jquery

i have script which displays iframe after certain seconds.

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
setTimeout(function(){
$(".hidden_div").show(function(){
$(this).find("iframe").prop("src", function(){
return $(this).data("src");
});
});
}, 5000);
});//]]> 
</script>
```

But it works with only code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js i am using wordpress's jquery 1.12.4

If i use both then i get lot of jquery errors from theme.

how to make the script work with 1.12.4 jquery?

Comment: You have a callback function in the `.prop` function, I'm not sure that's valid. Why don't you just have the `.hidden_div` show after 5 seconds instead of trying to mess the with iframe's src attribute?

Comment: @Xhynk i am trying to 5 secs lazy loading of the iframe

Comment: Nothing to do with WordPress.

Comment: @MaxYudin i am using this in wordpress.

Comment: You can use it with SolarQwertyJS-SMTH-built-10.143.234 but there is no problem with  WordPress.

Comment: @MaxYudin Do you still think it is nothing to do with wordpress??

Comment: @MaxYudin is right in that this isn't a WordPress specific problem. Any jQuery loaded into a document in compatibility mode requires the `$` alias to be defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have one iframe, just set the iframe's `src` attribute in the `.show()` callback function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    jQuery(window).load(function($){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.hidden_div').show(function(){
                $(this).find('iframe').attr('src', 'https://example.com/');
            });
        }, 5000);
    });//]]> 
</script>
```

If you need more dynamic code, remove the `src` attribute of the iframe, and add a new attribute with the url like so

```
<iframe data-src="https://example.com/"></iframe>
```

And then clone the data attribute to the src attribute like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    jQuery(window).load(function($){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.hidden_div').show(function(){
                var src = $(this).find('iframe').attr('data-src');
                $(this).find('iframe').attr('src', src);
            });
        }, 5000);
    });//]]> 
</script>
```

If you want to use the original code you have, this will work. The problem is you don't have the `$` jQuery alias defined yet.

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    jQuery(window).load(function($){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(".hidden_div").show(function(){
                $(this).find("iframe").prop("src", function(){
                    return $(this).data("src");
                });
            });
        }, 5000);
    });//]]> 
</script>
```

Comment: that did not work with 1.12.4 jquery.

Comment: A few things, why are you relying on such an outdated version of jQuery instead of 3.x? Also, I confirmed it is working with 1.12.4 as you can see here: https://codepen.io/xhynk/pen/QQoNeZ - Something else must be wrong. What error message are you getting?

Comment: I am using latest wordpress 4.9.4 and its default jquery is 1.12.4. I checked again. your solution works with 1.8.3 and did not work with 1.12.4

Comment: Are there any console error messages? Because you can see 1.12.4 working in the codepen I sent you.

Comment: yes. Uncaught TypeError $ is not function

Comment: Updated the code. You don't have the `$` jQuery alias set up. Change the first line to `jQuery(window).load(function($){` instead of `$(window).load(function(){`

Comment: And at that rate you could probably just use your original code replacing the first line with `jQuery(window).load(function($){`

Comment: Also, please mention in your answer that in wordpress jquery should be used instead of $.

Comment: You don't need to use the written `jQuery` function instead of `$`. The default jQuery included with WP is in compatibility mode to prevent conflicts with other libraries that use `$`. To enable this, you can define the `$` alias in the document ready or window load function, or by calling your functions with `(function($) { })( jQuery );`. This isn't a matter of "WordPress requires `jQuery()` not `$`, you just need to define the alias first.

Answer (score -1):

It's jQuery issue, not WordPress related, try with

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery(".hidden_div").show(function(){
            jQuery(this).find("iframe").prop("src", function(){
                return jQuery(this).data("src");
            });
        });
    }, 5000);
});//]]> 
</script>
```

Comment: This worked. after learning that we should use jquery instead of $ in WORDPRESS, i came back here and saw your answer. So, issue was jquery and wordpress.